# Incremental Database development in Entity framework code first

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-4.1, ef-code-first

How can I do incremental developments with entity framework code first database. Because  if I change something i model classes it will regenerate the database which  cased to loss my data already in the database. I'm using `DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges` . Is there any thing other than that to execute alter quires rather than recreating.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

EF Code First Migrations would help you here, it's in alpha/CTP currently: [Entity Framework Code First Migrations: Alpha](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/EntityFrameworkCodeFirstMigrationsAlphaNuGetPackageOfTheWeek10.aspx), also check out the [ADO.NET team blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2011/07/27/code-first-migrations-august-2011-ctp-released.aspx):

> The most consistent request we have heard from you since releasing EF
>   4.1 has been for a migrations solution for Code First that will
>   incrementally evolve the database schema as you model changes over
>   time. Today we are announcing the release of our first Community
>   Technical Preview (CTP) of our Code First Migrations work.

Answer (score 0):

As I recall, the Microsoft docs tell you to be sure *not* to use `DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges` in production environments. The point of that option is to help you come up with code-based data population for your test runs. I haven't seen any tools to help with incremental changes when using code-first. Where I work, we use a database-first setup, and we create a change script for each new release that includes alter and insert statements.

Answer (score 0):

incremental database development is not currently available in the current version of the codefirst framework however it is included in the roadmap for the next release which will ship with MVC 4

as of right now you would need to remove metadata tracking from the database conventions and update the database manually via scripting or using the sql tooling  until this new convention is added to the framework